# Changing Date Format -PHP / SQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I've got a piece of code which involves dates but wanted to change the format of the date; it has been set (as default by MYSQL) to `YYYY/MM/DD` however I want it so that it is in the form `DD/MM/YYYY`. How can I change this?

Comment: [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? There are thousands of tutorials on date formatting. Research first, ask last.

Comment: note: if you ever store files on your computer as dd-mm-yyyy you will see that all the 1st days of the month are grouped together. However if you use yyyy-mm-dd they are ordered correctly :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date( 'd/m/Y', strtotime( $date ) );
```

This should work although are you sure mysql isn't defaulting to yyyy-mm-dd as is the norm

**UPDATE FOR COMMENT**

```
$date = "2013-03-01";
date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime( $date ) );
```

Output: 01-03-2013

**UPDATE FOR COMMENT 2**

```
$loan_date = date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime($_POST['loan_date'])); 
$return_date = date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime($_POST['return_date']));

echo $loandate;
echo $return_date;
```

Working example in this case I just replaced the post vars with example strings but shows it works.  If its not working then check your input strings but it should work with ANY format date stamp.
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/viu-ghp

Comment: thanks, the date was set to yyyy-mm-dd but i'd rather it was dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: same still applies see the updated answer above.

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm doing the right thing: I have these two variables that are being passed via POST from a form:                               $loan_date = ($_POST['loan_date'] );
$return_date = ($_POST['return_date'] );

Comment: Updated with code using your input vars and posted an example of working code too

Comment: Remember this is only for output mysql will always store it internally in the YYYY-mm-dd format

Comment: oh, so i can't save the dates into a table in the form dd-mm-yyyy?

Comment: You'd have to reconfigure mysql to store dates internally in a different format. Which is a pain in the ass. Let mysql store dates however the hell it likes and just reformat them on display either using the line above or as suggested in the other comment reformat on select.  Personally I use my code above wrapped in a function mysql2uk() and then whenever I want to spit out a date in uk format of dd/mm/yyyy I just call my function around the variable from mysql and it does the work for me.  Use it everywhere its less overall code than putting the conversion in the sql query

Comment: oh I see, so what if I ask a user to enter the date in the uk format for example they enter ... 01-03-2013 for the loan date and 01-04-2013 for return date, how can i then change it to the way mysql stores it?

Comment: exact reverse of the code above it becomes `$return_date = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['return_date']));`

Comment: ah i just figured that out ahah, thanks for all your help! really appreciate it! (im a college student so this is all new to me)

Comment: The php docs website is brilliant for finding out what does what and how to use it. So for example you were looking for date formatting so searching the php site for "date format" gives this page http://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=+date+format&scope=quickref which gives you the first result for date() which gives you everything you need to do what you wanted to do :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to update the value of the column because of different format, leave it as it as it is already `DATE`. It is better to save date as `DATE` that `VARCHAR`.

However, you can change the format during the projection of the column (*SELECT statement*)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(colNAME, '%d/%m/%Y') as newDATE
FROM   tableNAme
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the DateTime class rather than the PHP's older date handling functions:

```
$dateFromSQL = "2013-03-01";

$dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat($dateFromSQL, 'Y-m-d');
print $dateObj->format('d/m/Y');
```